How do you check if a local max or min on the boundary is an global extrema
Given that $f(x,y)$ is defined on some half open half closed set, like $x^2+y^2<25$ for $y\geq 0$ and $x^2+y^2\leq 25$ for $y<0$. Two questions:

Can you have a local min/max on the boundary? Like if when constraining the function to just $x^2+y^2= 25$ for $y<0$, we find a local max/min, does that translate to a local extrema of the function on the entire set?

How can you tell if an extrema on the boundary is a global max/min? For example, if the function only contained a local min in the interior, how could we know that the function does not achieve a higher value than the extrema on the boundary without being a local extrema itself?



For those on the boundary, use y in terms of x or t in terms of x and y.

How does that help here?

Yes, boundaries can have local extrema. Beware: a local extremum found when restricting to the boundary may not be locally extreme in the entire set. A local maximum on a boundary curve, for example, may see the function increase as you head into the interior of the set. All that said, to find global extrema, find all the critical points in the interior and on the boundary (hopefully there are finitely many) and compute the function at each of these points. The maximum value is the global maximum, and same for the minimum (regardless if this is on the boundary or in the interior).

@TheoBendit what about for something like this? https://www.desmos.com/3d/70kemmpqxg where the only defined boundary is $x^2+y^2=1$. There are no other local min/max

Or for a simpler example, if we consider $f(x)=x^2$ on $[2,1)$, we know there is a local min at $x=0$ and that it is possible for $x=2$ to be a local max. How would we verify that it is without using proof by obviousness, as EVT does not apply here?
